# Can Google BigQuery read files from Google Cloud Storage private folder from Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: google-play, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Google Play Developer Console provides access to a Google Cloud Storage folder with User Acquisition analytics data for my app at;

gs://pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXX/acquisition/retained_installers

Can I get BigQuery to read from this data source?

If not, is there some way to link Google Play app analytics data to BigQuery (without Firebase)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment, google play uses a different encoding which could not be loaded directly into bigquery. Fortunately we are having a new feature just for this:)

Please check the [BigQuery Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-service-overview). It didn't mention Google Play because that's still in early stage.

If you are interested, you could

1. Finish the [Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer#before_you_begin) section. That page is for 
   adwords, but the prerequisite is the same
2. Fill the [enrollment 
   form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfOFHZCkhHpFyLJmHhq5r9Q1fUy5tj9lefJ1Nt2FtSVKBSCJw/viewform?c=0&w=1) and you will find play listed there.
3. After that we will send you more guidelines about ingesting data for Google Play.

Comment: Thanks Xuejian, the data transfer service works great.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can [query a federated table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage) where the files are stored on GCS. From the UI, you can open the add table dialog using the drop-down menu next to your data set, then specify a path, file type, etc. for the external table.

The benefit of linking with Firebase, or manually uploading from GCS yourself into BigQuery storage, is that your queries will be much faster due to the internal, optimized storage format.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

There seems to be some problem with that method, I assume because I do not own Google's own Play Cloud folder in GCP. The error code is "Error: Something went wrong with the table you queried. Contact the table owner for assistance."

Comment: Do you have a sample job ID for the failed query (or does this happen when you try to create the table)? I'd like to see what's wrong with the permissions.

Comment: The job ID from the failed table create is 'bigq-drd-1:bquijob_5281c88d_15cce748e91'
My understanding is that Google Play has to allow me permission to read from this bucket with BQ.

Comment: I don't see anything more useful in the job information on our end, unfortunately, just the same error that you do. To confirm, though, are you able to access the file(s) on GCS through the [Cloud Storage browser](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser)?

Comment: The detailed error is "Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered.". Probably because google play is using UTF-16LE encoding...

Comment: I am able to view and download the file from the browser.

Comment: I think Xeujian figured out what the problem was (the file encoding). Did you try out the data transfer service?

Comment: Thanks Elliott, the data transfer service is just what we needed.